# Удалить записи из нескольких связанных таблиц

Tags: sql

Делал таблицы при помощи СУБД SQL Server,я знаю что есть ON DELETE CASCADE, но не знаю как его проставить в SQL server. Как можно сформировать запрос при помощи inner join что бы удалить свзязанные записи из 3 таблиц?
Вот моя БД, удалить надо строку "номер_группы" из таблица "Группы". Зарание спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В SQL-server невозможно удалить одним запросом записи из нескольких таблиц. Придется воспользоваться несколькими запросами:

```
delete from [Журнал]
 where [номер_студента] IN(
    select [номер_студента] from [Студенты] where [Номер_группы]=XX
   );

delete from [Студенты] where [Номер_группы]=XX;

delete from [Группы] where [Номер_группы]=XX;
```

Но гораздо лучше все таки переделать внешние ключи и использовать `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Для этого ключи надо будет скорее всего пересоздать. Т.е. удалить их с помощью `alter table X drop constraint Y` и создать заново с помощью `alter table X add constraint Y foreign key ... on delete cascade`